# JWT Authentication error (Laravel) - token not provided

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, jwt

I have been battling with JWT for days! I've checked all the solutions I could find, I'm getting token_not_provided. It's tymon/jwt-auth version 'dev-develop' (newest non-dev is 1.0.0rc-3 at the time of posting) and I'm using it with Laravel 5.6.

While on locally it works fine, after uploading it to Cloudways it starts saying token_not_provided. I have tried changing the .htaccess file in the public drive, and also added another copy in the route directory just in case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Also here is my AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use JWTAuth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(RegisterFormRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => $user
        ], 200);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ( ! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response([
                'status' => 'error',
                'error' => 'invalid.credentials',
                'msg' => 'Invalid Credentials.'
            ], 400);
        }

        return response([
            'status' => 'success'
        ])
        ->header('Authorization', $token);
    }

    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->load('interest');

        return response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'data' => $user
        ]);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {

        $post = Post::find($id);

        return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post'));

    }

    public function refresh()
    {
        return response([
            'status' => 'success'
        ]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        JWTAuth::invalidate();

        return response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Logged out Successfully.'
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

Here is my api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('conv/store', 'ConversationController@store');
Route::post('interest/store', 'InterestController@store');
Route::post('message/store', 'MessageController@store');
Route::post('message/{id}/conv', 'MessageController@show');
Route::get('conv/{id}', 'ConversationController@show');
Route::get('get/users', 'AutoCompleteController@getUsers');
Route::get('subscribed/{pageTitle}/{UserInt}', 
'ConversationController@isSubscribed');
Route::get('categories', 'CategoryController@show');
Route::get('{id}/recommended', 'CategoryController@recommended');
Route::get('interests', 'InterestController@getAll');
Route::post('subscribe/{id}/{int}/add', 'InterestController@subscribe');
Route::post('subscribe/{id}/{int}/remove', 
'InterestController@unsubscribe');
Route::get('interest/profile/{id}', 'InterestController@show');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('auth/register', 'AuthController@register');
Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function(){
Route::get('auth/user', 'AuthController@user');
Route::post('auth/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.refresh'], function(){
    Route::get('auth/refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::get('/{id}/profile', 'AuthController@refresh');
});
```

Here is my auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
  ],
];
```

hope you can help!! Sorry if I've left anything out! If there's anything else you need me to add let me know.

Comment: Update: adding 'api' middleware to the /auth/user route causes 'couldn't find id of non-object', The original entry 'jwt.auth' gives me UNAUTHORIZED_REQUEST.

Comment: Just in case, although i don't think this will work for you, give it a try:

`php artisan cache:clear` and  `php artisan config:cache`

These two will clean your app and config cache.

And this to generate the token: `php artisan jwt:secret`

Run these commands in the sv.

Comment: hm interesting now I'm getting: "message": "Argument 2 passed to Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Hmac::createHash() must be an instance of Lcobucci\\JWT\\Signer\\Key, null given, called in C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Kita's website\\Interested-dev\\interested-dev\\vendor\\lcobucci\\jwt\\src\\Signer\\BaseSigner.php on line 34",

Comment: It seems like your key is empty? O.o weird as you have just created one... 

Try running  `php artisan jwt:secret -vvv` to see if anything goes wrong in that command

Comment: same message :/

Comment: ok I put it in postman and it came back with Method App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::respondWithToken does not exist. even though I can't find that method mentioned there. missing model?

Comment: of says success this time in postman, and has an Authorization token in the headers

Comment: Hm ok so on postman I noticed that while using the official website URL it gets a success, but localhost:8000 returns the above error. do I need to change it throughout the project? Which files would I need to change?

Comment: what is the oficial website? I'm a little out, right now

Comment: after review I don't think that's it. I ran php artisan route:clear too and I got back to unauthorised request.

Comment: :S I'll think and try to come with a solution!